# Google BigQuery SQL for summing individual columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm after an efficient(ish) BigQuery SQL query to address the following:

I've got a table that looks like so:

```
    
    Row | Col_A | Col_B |
    ---------------------
     1  |   2   |   3   |
     2  |   1   |   4   |
     3  |   5   |   7   |
     4  |   2   |   3   |
     5  |   6   |   1   |

    ...and so on (>million rows)
```

The value of each column is an ID with the range [1..7].

The query should produce the following i.e. sum every code for each column:

```
    
    Code | Total Col_A | Total Col_B
    --------------------------------
      1  |      1      |      0  
      2  |      2      |      0  
      3  |      0      |      2  
      4  |      0      |      1  
      5  |      1      |      0  
      6  |      1      |      0  
      7  |      0      |      1
```

Anyone know of a way of doing this in BigQuery without using multiple SELECTs?

Cheers.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you create a public dataset with your sample data? It will make much easier writing a query that works on your data, and validating the results.

A starting query:

```
SELECT Code, COUNT(Col_A) count_column_x, COUNT(Col_B) count_column_y
FROM [your:list.of_codes] a
LEFT JOIN EACH [your:sample.table] b
ON a.Code=b.Col_A
GROUP BY 1
```

(it's not perfect, will go further if you share a table to work with)

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone know of a way of doing this in BigQuery without using multiple SELECTs?

One SELECT with Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH logs AS (
  SELECT 2 AS Col_A, 3 AS Col_B UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS Col_A, 4 AS Col_B UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS Col_A, 7 AS Col_B UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS Col_A, 3 AS Col_B UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS Col_A, 1 AS Col_B   
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  SUM(CAST(id = Col_A AS INT64)) AS Total_Col_A, 
  SUM(CAST(id = Col_B AS INT64)) AS Total_Col_B
FROM logs, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,7)) AS id
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

Or with [COUNTIF()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#countif)

```
#standardSQL
WITH logs AS (
  SELECT 2 AS Col_A, 3 AS Col_B UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS Col_A, 4 AS Col_B UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS Col_A, 7 AS Col_B UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS Col_A, 3 AS Col_B UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS Col_A, 1 AS Col_B   
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  COUNTIF(id = Col_A) AS Total_Col_A, 
  COUNTIF(id = Col_B) AS Total_Col_B
FROM logs, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,7)) AS id
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```